# how to overwrite the nested array object in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object

I would like to know how to merger and overwrite the already existed object value in nested array in javascript.

As shown below, i need to merge the other_obj to obj with id = "zen" and overwrite if the property exists else merge

```
var obj =[
{id:"abc", 
amount: "100", 
fee: "5.5"},
{id:"xyz", 
amount: "1000", 
fee: "5.5"},
{id:"zen", 
amount: "500", 
fee: "5.5"}]

var other_obj = {
amount: 600,
name: "new"
}


Expected Output: 
{
id:"zen",
amount: 600,
fee: "5.5",
name: new
}
```

Comment: what is the relation between input and output?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] (you get a badge!) and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Your best bet here is to do your research, [search](/help/searching) for related topics on SO, and give it a go. ***If*** you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [mcve] of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help.

Comment: @brk how to get the expected output with above obj, other_obj  as input in javscript

Comment: @Senthil making no sense , you have an array of objects then you have a single object, how expected output is related to this array of object and `other_obj`

Comment: @brk yes i dont know whether its possible that's why posted , if you have solution please let us know , thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use `...` spread syntax:

```js
var obj = [{
    id: "abc",
    amount: "100",
    fee: "5.5"
  },
  {
    id: "xyz",
    amount: "1000",
    fee: "5.5"
  },
  {
    id: "zen",
    amount: "500",
    fee: "5.5"
  }
];

var other_obj = {
  amount: 600,
  name: "new"
};

var test = {};
obj.forEach(e => test = {...test, ...e});
test = {...test, ...other_obj};
console.log(test);
```

Comment: The `forEach` sets `test` to the last object of `obj` array.

Comment: Hi @Jack Bashford, can you explain how you have remove all object element expect last one, i don't understand what is e in foreach